# ASP net MVC: How to ignore one get variable with route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have url: `http://url.com/segment1?id=885&variable_need_to_ignore=value`

I need to exclude last variable (`&variable_need_to_ignore=value`) from url and process it without variable (ideally without redirect, on the same page) `http://url.com/segment1?id=885` (with route config ideally).

Answer (score 2):

You could change those from query string parameters to URL path parameters. [Check out this](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/). IMHO that would make your URLs cleaner and follow more of a RESTful paradigm.

If not then what about just creating a route to "http://url.com/segment1" and ignore the query string parameter "variable_need_to_ignore" inside your code.

It still leaves the questions: why do you need to ignore it and why is it in the URL in the first place if you are not in need of it?

**EDITED**

If the incoming parameters are out of your control and you need to ignore them, then just ignore them in your code. Since the resource exists at the URL you provide, IMHO, a 404 isn't really a valid response in your situation. The query string should really be used for some kind of filter on the results you would return, it should not be all the required parameters in the first place.

Comment: thanks for reply. I need to ignore it because there is social network script that add some get parameter to quoted URL. I send 404 status code if there was at least 1 unknown get-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a new route in RouteConfig.cs, and this should ideally be before the default route, somewhat similar to

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyCustomRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{variable_to_ignore}",
                defaults: new { variable_to_ignore = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Your action method should have two parameters - id, and variable_to_ignore.

Comment: thanks for reply. It would be problematically for me to add that parameter to all my actions.

Comment: if you don't have that parameter (i.e., variable_to_ignore) in your action, then why would need to ignore it! probably, I couldn't understand your question. Could you please update your question, may be you need to show people signature of your action.

Comment: There is social network script that add some get parameter to quoted URL. I send 404 status code if there was at least 1 unknown get-parameter.